# sha1sum into the URL of curl using GET method

Tags: bash

I'm writing a document for a curl request.

User should enter email and password, and I need to send user's email and **sha1sum of the password** via GET method.

If that would be right, the command would look like:

```
curl 'http://example.com/auth?email={EMAIL}&pwd={SHA1SUM(PASSWORD)}'
```

I know about `printf variable | sha1sum`, but how should I use it to concatenate to the quoted string of `CURL`?

Please not that it should stay a ONE line command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a command substitution using `$()`. You should use double quotes on the URL in this case (assuming a `$PASSWORD` variable):

```
$ curl "http://example.com/auth?email={EMAIL}&pwd=$(echo "$PASSWORD" | sha1sum  | sed -e 's|\w*-$||')"
```

(Added sed to remove the trailing `-` from the sha1sum output.)

Comment: You really, really, really should use [proper quoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) around `$PASSWORD`.

Comment: Ha..whoops, that's a bad slip - yes, it most definitely should :) I'd add that it'd be preferable to have built up the string and done some validation / sanitization in the caller and/or some function or script block in the chain.